# Can I use Docker simply to set up the general environment of an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I don't want to dockerize every application but rather provide a docker image (similar to an AMI) with preinstalled software and libraries so I can easily deploy on a new EC2 instance. From there I may add files/changes manually. Is this the intended use of Docker for EC2?

Comment: Look into ECS https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own image by using a `Dockerfile` and run on an EC2 instance after installing the Docker daemon.

Or you can use [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) to manage your container across multiple EC2 instances.

You can also use other tools like [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org), [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io) or [Rancheros](http://rancher.com/rancher-os/) to manage your containers.